# "ERROR root: code for hash md5 was not found." when running virtualenv python3

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run a virtual environment in python using the following line:
`virtualenv -p python3 .venv`
However, I am receiving this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
   globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
   raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
   from virtualenv.__main__ import run_with_catch
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
   from .run import cli_run, session_via_cli
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/run/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
   from ..app_data import make_app_data
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/app_data/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
   from .read_only import ReadOnlyAppData
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/app_data/read_only.py", line 5, in <module>
   from .via_disk_folder import AppDataDiskFolder, PyInfoStoreDisk
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv/app_data/via_disk_folder.py", line 31, in <module>
   from hashlib import sha256
ImportError: cannot import name sha256
```

Am unsure how to troubleshoot this--am not sure exactly waht is going on. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OS is not mentioned. MacOS users have many questions posted here on this issue related to homebrew. It is related to openssl library or headers. First check if you are even able to simply `import hashlib` in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it with python 3 first verify that it is installed:

```
which python3
```

Then try `python3 -m venv .venv` instead of your virtualenv command, It should produce the same result. [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is a module than now comes with python and can be used to create virtual environments.

The error that you're seeing is likely due to use of an outdated virtualenv CLI tool.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the equivalent then to the following commands? `./.venv/Scripts/activate` and `./manage.py runserver`. I need to use these to run the server.

Comment: @edgecases the activate one is the same. I would use `python manage.py runserver` instead of `./manage.py runserver`, the latter should work in most cases, but the former will work every time

Comment: It sounds to me like you're following some outdated book or course. I highly recommend checking the official Django docs instead